# add/tagging members when creating a group

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

this script is for creating a group.

```
<?php
$db = new Group($conn);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['g_name'];
$desc = $_POST['g_desc'];
$file = $_FILES['image'];
$res = $db->g_create($name, $desc);

if($res) {
$path = $db->uploadImg($file);
$db->saveImageName($res, $path);

   }
}
    ?>
```

and when a user join the group i run this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.join').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#join_id').val(id);

});


function joinGroup(){
    var join_id = $('#join_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"../controller/group_controller.php",
        data:{ 
            "join_id": join_id
        },

        success:function(data) {

          window.open('../views/group.php','_self'); 
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

what i wanted to do is if im going to create a group i can add members to it. 
this is what my modal looks like to give you better understanding of what i want to make. saying im going to create a group and add 2 members on it something like that.but i dont know how to do it cause i know that my `function joingroup()` only works if i already created a group.
[image]

this is what my table looks like

**tbl_group**

```
id  | name  |members | desc
1   | blank |   1    | sample
2   | true  |   2    | test
```

**tbl_joingroup**

```
group_id | user_id
   1     |    2
   2     |    3
   2     |    6
```